# How to bind an array to custom indexer?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a singleton localization class with an indexer. You can access it like this:

```
Localize.Current[String key]
```

I also have a custom Binding class that transforms `string` into a call to this indexer:

```
{Translate MyKey}
```

This will set Mode (`OneWay`) on my the binding, source to `Localize.Current` (singleton) and also path to:

```
[$key$]
```

Where `$key$` is evaluated to `MyKey`. Then it is localized and replaced by a localized value.
Now I want to parameterize this binding with additional parameters. So I did this:

```
Localize.Current[String key, params String[] parameters]
{Translate MyKey, MyParameter1, MyParameter2}
```

I don't know how to set path in the binding to this, I've tried:

```
new PropertyPath("[$key$, (0)]", values) // where values is String[] from Translate
```

This doesn't trigger the indexer. It triggers the `Localize.Current[String key, String parameter]` indexer, if I add one, but not an arbitrary amount of arguments. I need a path that contains reference to array something like:

```
new PropertyPath("[$key$, $array_placeholder$], values)
```

Can't finding anything anywhere. Neither in documentation, nor Google. Anyone has experience how to achieve this? What to put instead of `$array_placeholder$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`PropertyPath` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertypath.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_PropertyPath__ctor_System_String_System_Object___) with path and parameters is defined like this.

```
public PropertyPath (string path, params object[] pathParameters);
```

The `pathParameters` argument is an array that holds an `object` for each index in your `path`. That means in order to pass your `values` **array** for the index zero in your property path,  it has to be the first value in the **parameters array**. Then, the appropriate indexer will be called.

```
new PropertyPath("[$key$, (0)]", new object[] {values});
```

If you pass `values` directly, the index zero in the path will get the first value **of that array**, a `string`.

Comment: So no chance of getting a reference to that values array to trigger the indexer this[String key, params String[] parameters]? Because if I call it from code it works. I can do Localize.Current["a","b","c"] and it will call indexer. But with path = ["a","b","c"] it doesn't trigger the indexer. Only if I make a this[String a, String b, String c]. That removes the option to have arbitrary amount of parameters.